# Combine array items based on partial array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a given multidimensional array like:

```
$givenArray = [
    'one__111__' => [ 'more' => '000'],
    'one__111__xyz' => [ 'more' => '000'],
    'hey__121__' => [ 'more' => '000'],
    'hey__121__abc' => [ 'more' => '000'],
    'zzz__212__' => [ 'more' => '000'],
    'zzz__212__b' => [ 'more' => '000'],
    'abc__3__' => [ 'more' => '000'],
];
```

I need to map the pairs if they start with the same key name. So `one__111__` and `one__111__xyz` is a pair.

The result should look like:

```
[
    ['one__111__'] => [
        [0] => ['one__111__' => ['more' => '000']],
        [1] => ['one__111__xyz' => ['more' => '000']]
    ],
    ['hey__121__'] =>
        [0] => ['hey__121__' => ['more' => '000']],
        [1] => ['hey__121__abc' => ['more' => '000']]
    ]
    ['zzz__212__'] =>
        [0] => ['zzz__212__' => ['more' => '000']],
        [1] => ['zzz__212__b' => ['more' => '000']]
    ]
    ['abc__3__'] =>
        [0] => ['abc__3__' => ['more' => '000']]
    ]
]
```

This is what I have tried. I believe it's O(n2)

```
$result = [];

foreach($givenArray as $key => $value) {
    foreach($result as $resultItemKey => $resultItemValue) {
        if(substr($key, 0, strlen($resultItemKey)) === $resultItemKey)  {
            $result[$resultItemKey][] = [$key => $value];
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $result[$key][] = [$key => $value];
}
```

I've searched for the array filter/reduce/map functions but couldn't find the "right" one. Which array function should be used? Like I guess I need an array function which iterates over every item and allows me to pass in the newly created array. Is there such function in PHP?

[PHP sandbox code to play with](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/822662364e33190e6c625f2f0fcd1bf308d093ac)

Comment: I take it there's no fixed length/structure to the key names?

Comment: @Nick that's right

Comment: Are the keys always sorted as shown in your sample data?

Comment: @Nick luckely yes, but could change in future

Comment: @caramba What if a child prefix has it's own children?

Comment: what do you mean @vivek_23 ?

Comment: @caramba Like `hey__121__`,`hey__121__abc`,`hey__121__abc_def` ?

Comment: `hey__121` would then have 3 children

Comment: @caramba Ok, there is a faster way than sorting since your keys aren't too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the keys are sorted as shown in your sample data, you only need to compare the current key with the last key that was inserted into the output array:

```
$result = [];
$resultItemKey = '#';  // something that a key can't start with
foreach($givenArray as $key => $value) {
    if(substr($key, 0, strlen($resultItemKey)) === $resultItemKey)  {
        $result[$resultItemKey][] = [$key => $value];
    }
    else {
        $result[$key][] = [$key => $value];
        $resultItemKey = $key;
    }
}
```

Output is too long to show here but is as desired.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TgGrK)

Note that if the keys are not sorted, you can always use [`ksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) to sort the array by them.

Comment: :facepalm,  so easy?! `$resultItemKey` can even be set to an empty string `$resultItemKey = '';` ...

Comment: @caramba no it can't be set to empty string, as `substr($key, 0, strlen($resultItemKey))` will return `''` regardless of the value of `$key`, which will then match `''`

Comment: but that could only happen if the key is empty right? I do always expect a key.. I guess `#` as initial value might be more bullet proof.

Comment: If a key was empty, *everything* afterwards would match it because the empty string is a substring of every other string. It doesn't seem as if that would be a valid scenario for your data.

Comment: On the other hand it could be `null` and an extra null check can be added to check if it's the first time. Might be easier than trying to find a string which is not the prefix of any key

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
$new = [];
$keys = [];
// Extract keys as per pattern
foreach ($givenArray as $key => $val) {
    preg_match('/[a-z]+\_+\d+\_+/', $key, $match);
    $keys[] = $match[0];
}
// filter array for each extracted keys
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $new[$key] = array_filter($givenArray, function($k) use($key) {
        return strpos($k, $key) !== false;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [one__111__] => Array
        (
            [one__111__] => Array
                (
                    [more] => 000
                )

            [one__111__xyz] => Array
                (
                    [more] => 000
                )

        )

    [hey__121__] => Array
        (
            [hey__121__] => Array
                (
                    [more] => 000
                )

            [hey__121__abc] => Array
                (
                    [more] => 000
                )

        )

    [zzz__212__] => Array
        (
            [zzz__212__] => Array
                (
                    [more] => 000
                )

            [zzz__212__b] => Array
                (
                    [more] => 000
                )

        )

    [abc__3__] => Array
        (
            [abc__3__] => Array
                (
                    [more] => 000
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I like the idea of generating the keys array first. And as my question is written the keys do have a pattern. In real life though those keys don't follow such pattern..

Comment: This is still O(n2) though, like your original code.

Comment: If the pattern is different and have a large number of data, then this should be avoided

Answer (score 1):

You could improve by sorting by key first and then "peeking" the next keys until you stop finding keys that start with the same string as the current key.

That should reduce you to O(n ㏒ n):

```php
ksort($givenArray); // Or clone it first if you want to maintain the original array

$result = [];
for ($i=0;$i < count($givenArray);$i++) {
    $thisKey = array_keys($givenArray)[$i]; // O(1)
    $result[$thisKey] = [ $thisKey => [ $givenArray[$thisKey] ] ];
    while ($i < count($givenArray)-1 
          && substr(array_keys($givenArray)[$i+1], 0, strlen($thisKey)) === $thisKey) {
            $result[$thisKey][array_keys($givenArray)[$i+1]] = $givenArray[array_keys($givenArray)[$i+1]];
            $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for prefix match and add operations, you can build a [`trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. Each node will carry it's own children and the data it will hold finally when many keys have the same prefix.

```
<?php

class Node{
    public $char,$data,$children,$end,$key;
    function __construct($char){
        $this->char = $char;
        $this->data = [];
        $this->children = [];
        $this->end = false;
    }
}

class Trie{
    private $root,$result;
    function __construct($data){
        $this->root = new Node('~');
        $this->result = [];
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $this->insert($key);
        }
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $this->add($key,$value);
        }
    }

    private function insert($key){
        $temp = $this->root;
        $len = strlen($key);
        for($i=0;$i<$len;++$i){
            if(!isset($temp->children[$key[$i]])){
                $temp->children[$key[$i]] = new Node($key[$i]);
            }
            $temp = $temp->children[$key[$i]];
            if($temp->end) break;
        }
        if(!$temp->end) $temp->key = $key;
        $temp->end = true;
    }

    private function add($key,$value){
        $temp = $this->root;
        $len = strlen($key);
        for($i=0;$i<$len;++$i){
            $temp = $temp->children[$key[$i]];
            if($temp->end) break;
        }
        $temp->data[] = [$key => [$value]];
    }

    public function getResult(){
        $this->getResultHelper($this->root);
        return $this->result;
    }

    private function getResultHelper(Node $root){
        if($root->end){
            $this->result[$root->key] = $root->data;
            return;
        }

        foreach($root->children as $key => $node){
            $this->getResultHelper($node);
        }
    }
}

print_r((new Trie($givenArray))->getResult());
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/ag5pF

In the above code, we first build a Trie of nodes of keys and mark `end` for appropriate nodes(keys which end first) in `insert()`. Now, in `add()` method, we add the actual data of key value pair for these Trie nodes and finally get the result with the help of `getResult()`.

Time complexity should be nearly ~ `O(n)` since key lengths seem to be max 10 approx. Even it it's 100 on average, it would be O(n * 100) ~ O(n).